# How to place a number of objects of a known area randomly into a larger, known area without anything overlapping

Tags: math

Say I have a number of 2D boxes, I know all their dimensions, I need to place them randomly in a larger 2D box without them overlapping. The total area of the larger box is equal to or greater than the combined area of all the smaller boxes. What's the best way to randomly place the smaller boxes and check there's no overlap, without doing something like running the random placement function in a while loop until there's no overlap, because that could take a while or cause an infinite loop.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem ?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with design patterns IMO.

Comment: What's the question? How to place them without overlap (title), or how to randomly place them an determine whether there is overlap (body)?

Comment: sorry wasnt sure what to tag it. It's about how to place randomly (or at least seemingly randomly) without overlap in a defined area

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707669/trying-to-create-x-number-of-random-rectangles-by-iterating-through-loop-but-n) might be of interest to you.